# What affect does multiple imputation have on Type 1 error and should I subset data before MI?

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis, data-imputation

I'm conducting a hierarchical linear regression on a relatively small data set (n = 41) where missing data ranges from 0 to 47%. I have two questions about how multiple imputation (MI) may influence my results.

1. After conducting MI with 200 imputations using predictive mean matching and re-running my models, I noticed that there was a large jump in the number of predictors that are being found significant. How does MI affect type I error rates?
2. Although the data set is a small sample size, I have many more variables than I included in the model. Prior to conducting the MI, I subset the data frame to only those variables that are included in the model and a few demographic variables. Should I be including all available data prior to conducting the MI?

Comment: I recommend checking out this free book by the creator of `mice`: https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/

Comment: That is a very small sample size for MLM/HLM, and that's before knowing how many higher level groups are in your data. Can you tell us how many groups you have?